# assign a downloadable product to a customer magento 2

Tags: magento2, php

> I have created a plugin that allows customers to buy downloadable
>   products as a customer and creates a user for them. It assigns the
>   order to the customer, they receive an invoice. On the admin side I
>   can see the order assigned to them ( it has a status of complete ) and
>   on their account, they can see the order. When they check their
>   account under `my products` it is not there. This is in Magento 2. How
>   do I assign the product to the customer so they can download it?

Comment: So I am creating the order, then creating the customer and assigning the order to the customer. I believe assigning the order after creation is causing the issue.

Comment: I have found that the downloadable link is not having it's customer Id set any help with this would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Upon creation of the order, the links are given the customer id of the order. Since, I created the order with no customer id and then assigned only the order a customer id, the link was always missing the customer id.

```
/*
 * @var $this->downloadLink = \Magento\Downloadable\Model\Link\PurchasedFactory;
 */
 $items = $order->getAllItems();
foreach($items as $item){
    //look for downloadable products
    if($item->getProductType() === 'downloadable'){
        // create link from repository
        $link = $this->downloadLink->create()->load($item->getId(), 'order_item_id');
        $link->setCustomerId($customer->getId());
        $link->save();
    }
}
```